# Programatically getting the name of the .jar file that was started

Tags: java, spring

Is there a way to programmatically get the name of the `.jar` file that was executed? (through `Spring` or `Java`).

e.g. when running a Java application `java -jar myApp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no out of the box way to do this. But you can do something like following.

```
java -Djar.name=myApp.jar -jar myApp
```

And using following in code;

```
System.getProperty("jar.name");
```